# Transform array to assosiative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to change my $data format, so that it matches $x's format

```
   $x = [
        '021' => [
            'province' => 'jatim',
            'city' => 'surabaya'
        ],
        '031' => [
            'province' => 'jabar',
            'city' => 'jakarta'
        ]
    ];

    $data = [
        ['031', 'jatim', 'surabaya'],
        ['021', 'jabar', 'jakarta']
    ];
```

Comment: Any attempts to show?  Might look at `foreach`.

Comment: run $data thru foreach and compile new $x .. (please share your success)

Comment: `$x = array_combine(array_column($data, 0), array_map(function($value) { array_shift($value); return $value; }, $data));`.... PHP >= 5.5.0 to use `array_column()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `foreach` loops to iterate through your array.

```
$x = [];
foreach( $data as $d )
{
    $x[$d[0]] = ["province"=>$d[1],"city"=>$d[2]];
}
```

`$d[0]` represents the initial string ID.
`$d[1]` represents the province.
`$d[2]` represents the city.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result= array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
   $result[$value[0]] = array('province'=>$value[1],'city'=>$value[2]);
}
```

Explanation:
Create resulting array. Fetch through provided array to insert data in resulting array. If needed unset data array if no longer needed.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard This code is self-explanatory for anyone who understands php syntax.

Comment: True @RuslanN but there are thousands of PHP newbies visiting StackOverflow each and every day. The vast number of these do not understand the syntax. In addition, a well explained answer generally earns you more IIP's.